# How do I stop windows from corrupting my linux boot partition?

Tags: arch-linux, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I tripple-boot Arch, Ubuntu, and Windows 11, and it seems that every time I boot into Windows it corrupts my Arch boot partition.

On the boot partition is a `FOUND.000` folder which seems to be where windows puts corrupted files after "repairing" a disk. It contains what appear to be several copies of `initramfs-linux-fallback.img`, `initramfs-linux.img` and `vmlinuz-linux` judging by the file sizes.

I have two hard drives, one encrypted one with Ubuntu for work, and one that's split between Arch and Windows for personal use. I used to have grub installed on the EFI partition Windows made, but that ran out of space. So rather than moving and resizing a bunch of reserved Windows partitions I just made a new boot partition and moved grub there. Since then, it has regularly rendered my Arch installation unbootable with the following error:

[image: error premature end of file vmlinuz-linux]

I hope this is not too off-topic since it's Windows that's doing "restoration", but maybe Linux that's not cleanly unmounting the partition or something?

I did just notice that the windows boot partition has slightly different flags than the one I've made. No idea if it'll help. It doesn't seem normal for *any* type of disk for Windows to just randomly restore it every time.

Of course the first thought when facing corruption is actual actual corruption but the SMART status of the SSD is completely clean and they are fairly new drives. So it's not just random corruption, it seems something specific that's messing with it.

Comment: When multi-booting with Windows in the mix, disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must. Start with that.